# ReSharper/Linq error: Access to modified closure

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

In a validation `.cs` file on my ASP MVC 3 site, I am trying to run a quick check against the database for the existence of an agent ID number the user has entered in. However, ReSharper is identifying an error under the `agentId` variable that reads `Access to modified closure`. I am not sure what this error means or what is wrong with this statement in any way.

This is a helper method that we wrote into the Validation program. It is not set on a loop, but instead called from up above whenever an agent Id is detected in one of five places.

Here is the code that calls `StatValidation`

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(agt.AgencyId1))
{
   _sb.Append("One Agency Id is required; ");
}
else
{
    StatValidation(agt.AgencyCompany1, 
              agt.AgencyId1.Trim(), agt.AgencyIdType1, 1);
}

//Conditionally validate remaining Agent IDs
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(agt.AgencyId2) || 
    !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(agt.AgencyCompany2))
{
    StatValidation(agt.AgencyCompany2, agt.AgencyId2, agt.AgencyIdType1, 2);
}
```

And here is the method header and lines of code giving the error

```
private static void StatValidation(string company, 
      string agentId, string idType, int i)
{
   AgentResources db = new AgentResources();
   // ReSharper is highlighting 'agentId' with the error 
   // 'Access to modified closure'
   var check = db.SNumberToAgentId.Where(x => x.AgentId.Equals(agentId));

   if (check == null) _sb.Append("Agent ID not found; ");
```

Comment: Side note: your code is one pure copy-paste with huge amount of duplication. Please try to make more compact sample (and avoid posting copy-paste code - does not look good).

Comment: Noted both, edited the post. Thx

Comment: Thanks for removing extra calls. You likely missing most interesting piece of code in `StatValidation` function where you modify `agentId`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Access to modified closure` message means that your expression is capturing a variable that does/may have its value changed after capture. Consider the following

```
var myList = new List<Action>();

for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    myList.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}

foreach(var action in myList)
{
    action();
}
```

This will print the number `5` 5 times because `i` is captured by the expression, not the value of `i`. Since the value of `i` changes at each iteration of the loop, the value that will be printed by each action changes each time `i` does, eventually landing on `5` since it was the boundary condition for the loop.

As to the specific example you're giving, since `Where` is lazily evaluated (also, it'll never be null, it would just be an enumerable that fails to move to the next record on the first attempt), if you were to evaluate `check` by enumerating it again after your `if` statement, the *current* values of `agentId` at the time of iteration would be evaluated on, not necessarily the original value from the parameter.

To fix this, change:

```
var check = db.SNumberToAgentId.Where(x => x.AgentId.Equals(agentId));
```

to this:

```
var check = db.SNumberToAgentId.Where(x => x.AgentId.Equals(agentId)).ToList();
```

This forces the `Where` iterator to be evaluated only once, with the *current* value of `agentId` at that line, if `agentId` changes later in the method, that change will not affect the value of `check`.

Also, change:

```
if (check == null) _sb.Append("Agent ID not found; ");
```

to this:

```
if (check.Count == 0) _sb.Append("Agent ID not found; ");
```

To make your checks valid

Comment: if (!check.Any()) _sb.Append("Agent ID not found; "); is also good.